# Moving a UIView

Tags: objective-c, ios, animation, uiview

I am trying to move a UIView programmatically using the following method:

```
-(void)animatePlaybackLine: (int) currentBeat{
    CGRect newFrame = CGRectMake(currentBeat*eighthNoteWidth, 0, eighthNoteWidth, 320);
    [playbackLine setFrame:newFrame];
    NSLog(@"Line animated to %i", currentBeat);
    NSLog(@"New frame origin %f", playbackLine.frame.origin.x);
}
```

When the method is called, the NSLogs show that the variable currentBeat is incrementing as it should, and the frame of playbackLine (my UIView) appears to be moving as it should.  However, the object on the screen doesn't move.  I have also tried setting the bounds and the center instead of the frame, and all of them have similar results.  I also tried using an animation instead of setting the frame, to no avail.

Is there something else I should be doing to make the image onscreen show the changing frame?

Comment: Are you certain that `playbackLine` is not `nil` when this function is called? Are you calling `animatePlaybackLine:` in an `NSTimer` callback, or in some other way?

Comment: Thanks for the response -- playbackLine is definitely not nil. animatePlaybackLine: is being called in a while loop in another class that uses an NSTimer.  Does that answer your question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm guessing you're calling that method in a loop?  iOS isn't going to redraw the screen until your code finishes executing.  You can't loop like this and see iterative results.

To animate views, you should use the native support UIKit gives you.  In particular, check out [the Animations section in the UIView class reference](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/uiview_class/UIView/UIView.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006816-CH3-SW131).

Comment: I suspected it might be an issue with redrawing the screen.  I've tried using an animation: [UIView animateWithDuration:1 animations:^{playbackLine.frame = newFrame;}];  but it gives me the same results.  Is there a way to tell the viewController to redraw?

Comment: You don't have to tell the view controller to redraw if you are using the normal animation methods.  You've taken out the loop, right?  You don't need a timer, a loop, or anything like that.  The native animation support deals with it all for you.  Doing it manually is wrong.

Comment: The reason I was originally wary of using animation is because I need the visuals to be precisely synchronized with audio playback, but it seems the only way to do it is to use animation, so I'll just do that.  Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
    [UIView animateWithDuration:0.3
                      delay:0.0
                    options: UIViewAnimationCurveEaseOut
                 animations:^{
                     datePickerView.frame = imageFrame;
                 } 
                 completion:^(BOOL finished){
                     self.datePickerViewFlag = NO;
                 }];
```

Comment: This gives me the same results -- the UIView thinks its frame is changing, but it doesn't move in the display.